# Weird behavior in displaying textContent when there's overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a Calculator App and there I am noticing a weird glitch. When I enter `"1-1111...."` and the moment it overflows the `display div` width, the text in the `div` element jumps down to only `"1-"`, whereas if I inspect the `textContent` for div element its still `"1-1111...."`.

**To see for yourself just enter `1` then `minus sign` and then keep entering `1's` untill the display overflows. You will see what I am taking about. *View in FullScreen***

***Also this happens only with minus sign try inserting plus sign instead of minus it will work fine.***

```js
//Selectors
let numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers")
let operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operators")

let equalto = document.querySelector(".equalto")
let clear = document.querySelector(".clear")
let backspace = document.querySelector(".backspace")
let plusMinus = document.querySelector(".plus-minus")
let dot = document.querySelector(".dot")

let display = document.querySelector(".display")
let output = document.querySelector(".output")

let equaltoPressed = false;

//Event Listeners
for(let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
 numbers[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (equaltoPressed){
   display.textContent = "";
   equaltoPressed = false;
  }
  //if condition so that if the display has "Infinity" on it, we don't append digits
  if ("0123456789.+-×÷".includes(display.textContent[display.textContent.length-1]) || display.textContent == "")
   display.textContent += this.textContent;
  evaluate();
 })
}

for(let i=0; i<operators.length; i++){
 operators[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  equaltoPressed = false;
  if ("+-×÷".includes(display.textContent[display.textContent.length-1]))
   display.textContent = display.textContent.substring(0,display.textContent.length-1) + this.textContent;
  else
   display.textContent += this.textContent;
 })
}

equalto.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
 if (output.textContent !== ""){
  display.textContent = output.textContent;
  output.textContent = "";
  equaltoPressed = true;
 } 
});

clear.addEventListener("click", function(){
 equaltoPressed = false;
 display.textContent = "";
 output.textContent = "";
})


backspace.addEventListener("click", function(){
 equaltoPressed = false;
 display.textContent = display.textContent.substr(0,display.textContent.length-1);
 evaluate();
})


plusMinus.addEventListener("click", function(){
 equaltoPressed = false;
 let expression = display.textContent;
 let flag = true;

 for (let i=expression.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  if ("+-×÷".includes(expression[i])){
   if (expression[i] !== "-")
    expression = expression.substring(0,i+1) + "-" + expression.substring(i+1,expression.length);
   else if ("+-×÷".includes(expression[i-1]) || i-1<0)
    expression = expression.substring(0,i) + expression.substring(i+1,expression.length);
   else
    expression = expression.substring(0,i) + "+" + expression.substring(i+1,expression.length);
   flag = false;
   break;
  }
 }

 if (flag)
  expression = "-"+expression;
 display.textContent = expression;

 evaluate();
})


dot.addEventListener("click", function(){
 if (equaltoPressed)
  display.textContent = "";
 let start = 0;
 for (let i=display.textContent.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  if("+-×÷".includes(display.textContent[i])){
   start = i+1;
   break;
  }
 }
 if (!display.textContent.substring(start,display.textContent.length).includes("."))
  display.textContent += ".";
})

//Functions
function evaluate(){
 let expression = display.textContent;

 for (let i=0; i<expression.length; i++){
  if (expression[i] === "×")
   expression = expression.substring(0,i) + "*" + expression.substring(i+1,expression.length);
  if (expression[i] === "÷")
   expression = expression.substring(0,i) + "/" + expression.substring(i+1,expression.length);
 }

 if("0123456789.".includes(expression[expression.length-1]) && eval(expression) != expression)
  output.textContent = eval(expression);
 else
  output.textContent = "";
}
```

```css
*{
 border:0;
 margin:0;

}


body{
 height: 100vh;
 background: black;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 color: #f8f8f8;
}

.row{
 display: flex;
}

.light-grey{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #a6a6a6;
 height: 4.2rem;
 width: 4.2rem;
 border-radius:  50%;
 margin: .4rem;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: black;
}

.dark-grey{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #333333;
 height: 4.2rem;
 width: 4.2rem;
 border-radius:  50%;
 margin: .4rem;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.yellow{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #ff9501;
 height: 4.2rem;
 width: 4.2rem;
 border-radius:  50%;
 margin: .4rem;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#zero{
 width: 9.2rem;
 border-radius:0 50px 50px 0;
 border-top-right-radius: 50px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
 border-top-left-radius: 50px;
}

.display{
 width: 19.2rem;
 height: 3rem;
 margin: 0 .4rem 1.5rem .4rem;
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 3rem;

 padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
 overflow-y: hidden;
   overflow-x: scroll;
}



.output{
 width: 19.2rem;
 height: 2rem;
 margin: 0 .4rem 1.5rem .4rem;
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 2rem;

 padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
 overflow-y: hidden;
   overflow-x: scroll;
}

i{
 font-size: 1.3rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 19.2rem;
  height: .2rem;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: black;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #333333;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #a6a6a6;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Calculator</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-46r060N2LrChLLb5zowXQ72/iKKNiw/lAmygmHExk/o=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="display"></div>
 <div class="output"></div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="light-grey clear">AC</div>
  <div class="light-grey plus-minus">+/-</div>
  <div class="light-grey operators">÷</div>
  <div class="yellow backspace"><i class="fas fa-backspace"></i></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">7</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">8</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">9</div>
  <div class="yellow operators">×</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">4</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">5</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">6</div>
  <div class="yellow operators">-</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">1</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">2</div>
  <div class="dark-grey numbers">3</div>
  <div class="yellow operators">+</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="dark-grey numbers" id="zero">0</div>
  <div class="dark-grey dot">.</div>
  <div class="yellow equalto">=</div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you change `height:auto;` to `display` class, you will see other number.

Comment: @Simone Rossaini That is not what I want

Comment: you may try: white-space: nowrap;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `white-space: nowrap` to `.display`, so the text won't break with the dash.

If you change the font-size, you can see that the text is going down with the dash.

[image: Image showing how line breaks with dash]

Comment: Thanks you're a true genius! But can you please explain in a bit detail what is `white-space: nowrap` and how does it get effected only with dash, it would be very helpful, you see I am a Noob.

Comment: Thanks, @SomShekharMukherjee :)
Texts always will collapse to fill line boxes, newline characters in the text are handled the same as other white space. The "-" will represent a break in this behavior, so with `white-space: nowrap`, you can prevent the text from collapsed. You can read more about this property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space). I hope helped you :)